# VirtualBox: How to connect to Internet via wi-fi on Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed VirtualBox with a Win XP VM on my Mac running OS 10.7.5. 
My Mac only has a wi-fi connection to the internet. On the settings for the virtual host, I set:

- Attached to: Bridged Adapter
- Name: en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
- Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
- Promiscuous Mode: Deny
- Mac Address:
- Cable Connected: true

Those are the settings I see around the internet as being correct, but I still can't ping anything.

On my Mac I have internet sharing via Ethernet enabled (not sure if that matters).

When I start up my WinXP VM, it asks me to install a bunch of hardware which I don't have any drivers to. Do I need to install any ethernet card drivers in order for the internet to work?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that the driver was not installed. The image I downloaded did however have a driver mounted to a separate drive (for the intel pro 1000/mt network card). I installed it and it worked liked a charm!

I'm guessing that if your image doesn't come with the driver, you can download it again.

Comment: Can you provide instructions for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed the VirtualBox Ethernet device drivers on the guest, then the XP install won't be able to use the network. Install the necessary device drivers per the VirtualBox documentation (probably an "Install VirtualBox Additions" menu command or similar), and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

My Windows ISO I downloaded didn't have the XP controller installed. I finally figured it out. I downloaded file from: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/detail_desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18717 then transferred to the VirtualBox and installed. After installing it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

So I just changed the settings to NAT & Intel 1000 MT Desktop. This works for me.

Screenshot of macbook pro settigns on el capitan:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't need to mess around with any settings to get your Internet connection working. If it's working on your host OS (Mac) it will work on your guest OS (Win XP).

As I understand it, VirtualBox should handle connecting to your host's Internet (wifi in your case) automatically. The Internet connection appears as a wired network connection in your guest (Win XP) regardless of what kind of ethernet connection your host (Mac) has.